# Laravel RouteServiceProvider.php file

Tags: laravel

I'm relatively new to Laravel; using 8.26.1
just after creating a project, I noticed that I have RouteServiceProvider.php exists in two locations:
app\providers\ and  \vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\

can someone explain which one should I use to make my changes or guide me to a document where I can read about how and which file is used by Laravel ?

Answer (score 0):

You would be using the one in your application which is everything that isn't in `vendor` as that is all packages and you should not touch any of that. The `App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider` (`app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php`) is the provider that is loaded by your configuration in `config/app.php`. This extends the base one from Laravel to give it the features it needs.

Comment: Thanks, will use the one in app/providers; however previously , I included some debug on both to check which is  used by the process and noticed that is using the one in /vendor ;  why is that ?

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/8.x/config/app.php#L176  your application uses the one in your project ... that provider extends from the one in `Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider`